# Getting data from unusualy formatted field in database

Tags: php, mysql

we have a field in a database that stores the data as below:

```
a:4:{
s:10:"subscriber";
b:1;s:32:"access_s2member_ccap_one";
b:1;s:32:"access_s2member_ccap_two";
b:1;s:32:"access_s2member_ccap_three"; 
b:1;}
```

We need to grab all the ccaps that are in this field but don't know the best way to do it, we can return the above as a string from the field in the database but don't know what to do with it next. The ccaps will always start with access_s2member_ccap but the s:32 in front of it will change each time. We need to get all of them and in some cases there may be as little as one as well as more than three.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You have to [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) your data.